# How to check if an object property exists in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn chain of responsibility pattern in Java, In below code if the successor does not exist, it gives a `NullPointerException`. I want to check if the successor exists like this

```
if(this.sucessor exists) {
  this.successor.check(Home) 
}
```

How can I do this?

```
public void next(HomeStatus Home){
   this.successor.check(Home);
}
```

Comment: `if (this.successor != null)`

Comment: ohh thanks . didnt see that :)

Comment: you also can wrap the successor into an optional on java8+ - so checking that he is instanciated would be `successor.isPresent()` - good thing about it - it´s null-safe and you can also call `orDefault(<VALUE>)` so it will return a default value (or new object) if there would be null.

Comment: @LenglBoy this is nice

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it obvious ?

```
public void next(HomeStatus Home){
      if(this.successor != null){
          this.successor.check(Home);
     }
}
```